# Could a mapView.region.span.longitudeDelta or mapView.region.span.latitudeDelta be negative?

Tags: iphone, mkmapview, mkcoordinateregion

Could a mapView.region.span.longitudeDelta or mapView.region.span.latitudeDelta be negative ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The delta cannot be a negative value. Because it is a kind of distance and distance cannot be negative.

Comment: And trying to use region with negative span will result in an error